# Jquery sortable element

Tags: jquery, element, jquery-ui-sortable

How to access the jquery sortable element.

```
function dropMembers() {

        $("ul.present").sortable({
            connectWith: 'ul',
            containment: 'window'
            //containment: 'ADD_MEMBER_DIALOG'
//            sort: function(event, ui) {
//                var present_result=$("ul.present").sortable('toArray');
//               // alert(ui.sortable);
//            }

        });

        $("ul.usrlist").sortable({
            connectWith: 'ul',
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            containment: 'window'
//             sort: function(event, ui) {
//             var usr_result=$("ul.usr").sortable('toArray');
//             //alert(ui.sortable);
//            }
        });

        $("#USER_PRESENT_LIST, #MAIN_USER_LIST").disableSelection();

}`
```

In this function i want to filter an element of ul.usrlist that is made sortable ie. i want to make an element in ul.usrlist to be non sortable.
How can i do that

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [this demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#items) in the docs. Basically add a class of ui-state-disabled to the items you dont want to be sortable then pass in the items when you define the sortable.

e.g

**html**

```
<ul id="sortable1">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled">(I'm not sortable or a drop target)</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled">(I'm not sortable or a drop target)</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**js**

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
   items: 'li:not(.ui-state-disabled)'
});
```